# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in GUI_Login.DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am changing a console app login over to a web based application and recieve the following error about an Unhandled exception.

In the console app I have the following line of code which resides in the StoredProcDemo class:

```
 StoredProcDemo spd = new StoredProcDemo();
```

In the Web Application I have:

```
Login spd = new Login();
```

I am not sure what to change it over to. Could someone shed some insight thanks and maybe why? Thanks so much.

Here is the full code if needed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

namespace GUI_Login
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
            SqlConnection conn = null;
            SqlParameter parmReturnValue;

            Login spd = new Login();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
        }

        protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RunStoredProcParams();
        }

        public void RunStoredProcParams()
        {
            //run simple stored procure
            spd.RunStoredProcParams();

            int Result;
            Result = -1;

            conn = conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=c:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\DATA\\UserDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True; Integrated Security=SSPI");
            conn.Open();

            try
            {
                //create and open a connection object
                conn = conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=c:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\DATA\\UserDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True; Integrated Security=SSPI");
                conn.Open();

                //Create the command object indentifying the stored procedure
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("PassParamUserID", conn);

                //set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", txtUserName.Text));
                parmReturnValue = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", SqlDbType.Int);
                parmReturnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@UserId"].Value);
                conn.Close();

                // lblResult.Text = Result;
                if (Result > 0)
                {
                    lblResult.Text = ("User does exist in database");
                }
                else if (Result < 0)
                {
                    lblResult.Text = ("Denied, try another user name");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even ignoring `RunStoredProcParams` you'll get a stack overflow as soon as you try to create a new instance:

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    // Removed extraneous stuff...
    Login spd = new Login();
}
```

Why do you want every instance of `Login` to have a reference to *another* instance of `Login`, which it creates immediately?

Basically the constructor is going to be called recursively until it goes bang.

What are you *trying* to do here, and why? In the console app you may well be creating an instance of `StoredProcDemo`, but I'm sure it wouldn't be within `StoredProcDemo` itself (as an instance variable initializer). Perhaps it's in `Program` or something similar? That would make more sense.

Comment: Actually I had it in the Main statment for the console application. I am still an elementry programmer and must dive deeper into Interfaces and using them.

Comment: Jon, your fix worked. Could you refer me to documentation that I could read to understand more about using instances? I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks for saving my day once again.

Comment: @jpavlov: I suggest you start reading an introductory C# book, from the beginning. Diving in with web applications and stored procedures isn't a good way to learn, IMO - there are too many things which could confuse you, all at the same time.

Comment: @jpavlov: I think @Jon Skeet makes a great point.  You are jumping into topics that are all the more difficult let alone knowing C# correctly.  You need to start with a plain old C# book, from beginning to basic object oriented programming.  Once you understand C#, then you can start looking at books that deal with C# connecting to databases, etc.  Too many monsters at once will leave gaps in your knowledge.

Comment: @JonH Hey Plus one for great suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You run RunStoredProcParams() recursively indefinitely.

Comment out this line:

```
spd.RunStoredProcParams();
```

Also comment this one:

```
Login spd = new Login();
```

Comment: I get the same error? An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in GUI_Login.DLL

Comment: the compiler stops at Login spd = new Login();

Comment: @jpavlov: No, the *compiler* doesn't stop there. It will *compile* just fine - the fact that you're getting an exception at *execution* time shows that.

Comment: It's actually quite amazing that the constructor accepts to call itself :)